# Changing the datatype of a column

Tags: mysql

I created a table with couple of columns, and one of them is `VARCHAR(250)`.

I have a lot of rows in the table and I want to change the DataType of the column to `VARCHAR(500)`.

If I right-click on the table and select "alter table", I can change the column DataType.

Is it safe to change the DataType like this?

How else can I change the column DataType?

Is there is a possibility of losing data from the table when changing the DataType?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are modifying the `varchar(250)` to `varchar(500)` then its safe to proceed.  If you were changing from `varchar(500)` to `varchar(250)` then yes your data would be truncated.  Also, if you were changing data types like `varchar(250)` to `integer` then yes that would also affect your data.  You could use the graphical tool to modify your column or use the following statement from command line to alter your column:

```
alter table table_name modify column_name varchar(500);
```

or

```
alter table table_name change column_name column_name varchar(500);
```

Strongly suggest you to backup your table before doing this, just in case.

Comment: Be careful of your MySQL version as well -  in versions of MySQL lower than 5.0.3, VARCHAR cannot exceed 255 characters.  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)

Comment: @dethtron5000 I am using 5.2.47, it's ok to change it?

Comment: @dethtron5000, true only if that's the only column and is using `utf8` characters.  Otherwise the following clause (from the documentation): `The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used`